# Screenshot file much larger dimensionally than original

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen-capture

So I take a screenshot of an area with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> but when I open the screenshot file in Paint X, the image's dimensions are far larger than the original area.

Is there any way to take a screenshot that looks exactly like the taken part of the screen?

Comment: Are you perhaps on a Retina MacBookPro and the screenshot is exactly twice as big in each dimension?

Comment: Yes, retina and I think yes twice.. @AlanShutko

Comment: What setting is your display in the system preferencs? Would you object to an automated solution to resize the snaps or recommendation for another tool that makes it easy?

Comment: just wondering what are your settings in Paint X. Also does it open as large in any other programs like Preview?

Comment: It is in the 4th position not the smallest but the one before that. I would really if all my taken screenshots were like 50% smaller by default. @bmike

Comment: @Buscar웃 100% in paint x and in preview it automatically resizes it to fit the window.

Comment: @KorayTugay: Open it in Preview, then from the View menu choose "Actual Size" (shortcut: <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd>), and see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

Screenshots taken on a Retina display will be twice the size as screenshots taken on a non-Retina display.

Most software such as Preview will compensate for this, however I'm unfamiliar with Paint X and doubt it is correctly showing the image rather than the image being 'wrong'. Try using software optimised for a Retina display.

If you want take screenshots for non-Retina displays, you can use [RetinaCapture](http://www.retinacapture.com). Note that these screenshots at 100% on Retina displays in software optimised for Retina will be smaller than real size.

Comment: Exactly…the screenshots are exactly the same size as the display. The problem is with Paint X.

Comment: When I open the taken screenshot with browser it is still double the size so I really need to resize them.

Comment: @Koray Added link to suitable app